# Answering Amen on Tefilin

Tags: halacha, tefilin

I understand there is a machlokes whether the mitzvah of tefilin is 2 separate mitzvos or rather one mitzvah with 2 parts. Thus, in terms of blessings, some Ashkenazim make 2 but say ‘Baruch shem kvod malchuso’ - בָּרוּךְ שֵׁם כְּבוֹד מַלְכוּתוֹ לְעוֹלָם וָעֶד - at the end of the second in case it is actually an unnecessary blessing.

Can/should a person answer amen to the second blessing on tefilin, if it extraneous does this pose a problem?

Comment: I edited your post to clarify that this is just the Ashkenazi minhag - Sefardim only make the second bracha if they’ve interrupted between the two, and they don’t make a Baruch Shem in that case.

Comment: @doniel *only some Ashkenzim

Comment: @DoubleAA Huh. I did not realize that’s not universal. I’ll update my edit.

Comment: The minhag in Jekkisch minyonim is that we do indeed respond אמן to both berachot (sources: davening with Jekkisch minyonim and R' Binyomin Shlomo Hamburger שליט"א)

Answer (score 9):

R Jack Abramowitz at OU [answers](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/tues_11_15_11/) your question this way

> After adjusting the head strap, the person continues with “Baruch
> sheim k'vod malchuso l’olam vo’ed” (Blessed be the Name of He Whose
> glorious kingdom lasts forever) because there is some doubt
> as to the need for a second blessing on tefillin. **This doubt also
> raises the question of whether or not someone who hears the blessing
> “al mitzvas tefillin” should respond with “Amen,” so the [Kitzur
> Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.10.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) recommends that this blessing be recited quietly.**

[Kaf Hachayim 25:40](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.25.5?lang=bi&p2=Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.25.40.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) writes that **a Sephardi who hears the bracha on the Tefillin shel rosh is permitted to answer amen in his head** ([Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Putting_On_and_Removing_Tefillin#cite_note-64)).

Note that Sefaradim (following Rambam [Hilchot Mezuza 4:5](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925425/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-Four.htm)) and [Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/558788/jewish/Is-a-separate-blessing-recited-on-the-head-tefillin.htm) say only one blessing.

Answer (score 6):

The [Kitzur Orach Chayim 10:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.10.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that due to this uncertainty (see [Orach Chayim 25:5](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%94)) one should say this blessing in an undertone:

> וּמִפְּנֵי שֶׁיֵּשׁ סָפֵק בִּבְרָכָה זֹאת, לָכֵן יֵשׁ גַּם כֵּן סָפֵק אִם הַשּׁוֹמֵעַ יַעֲנֶה אָמֵן אוֹ לֹא (פרמ"ג). עַל כֵּן נִרְאֶה לִי כִּי טוֹב לְבָרֵךְ בְּרָכָה זֹאת בְּלָחַשׁ.
>
> (...) and because there is a doubt regarding this berachah **there is consequently also a doubt if one who hears the berachah should answer *Amen* or not.** Therefore, it appears to me that it is preferable to recite this berachah in an undertone.
>
> <sub>Translation from Sefaria</sub>

[R. Shlomo Kluger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Kluger) discusses in detail whether one could respond *amen* to this blessing in [Haelef lekhah Shelomoh](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1354&st=&pgnum=25). Regarding Sefardi authorities, Kaf haChayim repeats this custom, and if someone else said this blessing aloud, one should say *amen* silently in his heart (see also [Yalkut Yosef 1:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.28.54?with=all&lang=bi)):

> ואם ברך בקול רם ושמע חבירו, יש לענות אמן בלבו

However, at [DinOnline](http://din.org.il/2018/01/10/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9/) (based on Chacham Ovadia Yosef) the answer was that Sefardim are not required to respond at all:

> ובשו”ת [יביע אומר](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8) ח”א סי’ כט כתב, שאם השומע הוא ספרדי שמנהגו שלא לברך ברכה זו, לא יענה אמן.